# Cloud FireStore minimum deployment target

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the following error when trying to enable an app with Cloud FireStore:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Firestore` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I changed the podfile requirement to 10.2 and my xcode deployment to 10.2 and I am still getting this error.  Any suggestions?

#### Edit:

Solution for me: I did

```
pod repo update
pod install
pod update
```

in that order and it worked.

Comment: did you run `pod update` after changing the Podfile?

Comment: It was close to that.  I was adding to an existing project so I did pod repo update pod, pod install then pod update it that order and it worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was adding to an existing project so I did

```
pod repo update
pod install
pod update
```

it that order and it worked.

I'm not sure why this ordered worked, put my guess it would have something to clearing/reset something somewhere in the firebase add ons.

Comment: Install wasn't working for me even after the repo update but doing update then install worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, hopefully if my order doesn't work for some people yours will.

Comment: same as @BenSullivan. Thanks a lot !

Comment: this order did't work to fix `Firebase/Core` but it worked for everything else

Answer (score 7):

I did this in order :

Remove `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` from your Podfile, then :

```
pod repo update

pod update
```

Then I add `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` to my Podfile and finally perform `pod install`

Answer (score 2):

Firestore should work with iOS 7 and later. More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

The simplest Podfile that uses it looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

The Xcode deployment target for your app should not have any effect on `pod install`.

The [getting started video](https://youtu.be/iMkifTEaefE?t=2m42s) shows this all in action.

Comment: Yea I completely aware and I've gotten firebase realtime running along other firebase tools.  I've also had podfile errors before but not this.  I'm wondering if you have any insight into this specific error because general podfile help isn't what I need.  Thank you.

Comment: Short of sharing your actual Podfile I'm not sure what else I can say.

Comment: I totally appreciate you taking time to help, I was just asking if you had more tailored advice.  But either way thanks for taking the time!

Comment: This is getting too chit-chatty for stackoverflow. Can you ask this question on firebase-talk and we'll debug it there? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I tried `pod repo update`, `pod install`, `pod update` and even updated cocoapods.

Turned out I still had the `FirebaseDatabase` pod in the `podfile`.

Removing that solved the problem.

[image: pod result]

Answer (score 0):

That's it,

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had same problem (Specs satisfying the Firebase/Functions dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.) when I was trying to add firebase/Functions to my pod file.

After several tries I've solved by removing all pods and then running pod install for each pod line I wanted, one by one, not installing all at same time.
At the end I've found that the pod 'Firebase/Core' was the problem, and I installed it for last and now everything is installed fine.

This is my pod now.

```
def shared_pods
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Functions'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing FirebaseInAppMessaging (0.12.0)
Installing FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay (0.12.0)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with an another library.
Actually the last iOS version is 12. Also setting this version on the app, the error was still appearing.

The solution for me was to **delete the podfile.lock file** (I don't know why...)