# Firebase/MLVision is not getting installed via Pods iOS

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, mlvision

I'm trying to add Firebase/MLVision to my iOS app, but running pod install gives me this:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/MLVision":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/MLVision

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/MLVision` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

What do I do? Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

After trying different things for some time, I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613676/1585677

Basically removing the Firebase/MLVision from pod file, then running

```
pod repo update

pod update
```

Then adding Firebase/MLVision to Podfile and running `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Pod file is not valid, or isn't targeting your project. You can see a [working codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-ios/#0) here if you have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the ios version specified in the Podfile is too low. It needs to be at least 8.0 for Firebase 5.x, including the MLVision subspec:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```