# How To Solve Cocapods could not find the compatible Versions

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I  am using Firebase latest version in my unity 2018. While build  my project unity says

```
iOS framework addition failed due to a CocaPods installation 
failure.This will will likely result in an non-functional xCode 
Project.
```

This is my Pod file.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '5.4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '5.12.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '5.12.0'
pod 'Firebase/Database', '5.12.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '5.9.0'
pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '5.3.0'
end
```

When i try  to install pod  using

pod install .

It says

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod 
"Firebase/Auth":
In Podfile:
Firebase/Auth (= 5.12.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Auth (= 5.12.0)` dependency were 
found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have  update latest version of cocapods also...

But  the workspace is not created..

How to  solve the problem...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Update Firebase . Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592883/cloud-firestore-minimum-deployment-target/46613676) And check the versions of

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.

1) First you have change to .net3.5 to .net 4x

2) Update dotnet4 package....(firebase messaging, Dynamic etc to dotnet4 package)

3) Go and Search Unity.Compat,Unity.Task, Unity.Compat in dotnet45 Folder. Enable With your desired package(ios,Editor,Stand alone).

4) Deselect the Unity.Compat, Unity.Task in 3.5  Version. (ios,Editor, stand alone).

By following the above method . I have solved this error.