# I can't debug my code in VSCODE because of this error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
CocoaPods' output:
↳

```
  Preparing
Analyzing dependencies
Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)
Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud FireStore minimum deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592883/cloud-firestore-minimum-deployment-target)